Why do objects get axially magnified with lenses, but not laser pulses?
So I understand the axial magnification of an object being imaged by a lens using simple ray optics. But I don't understand why the same thing doesn't happen to laser pulses? For instance, if we ignore dispersion, a 100fs pulse is roughly 30um, and if i send it through a telescope, i expect it to stay 100fs, and thus 30um axially. But I would have magnified it laterally based on the telescope.
So where is the difference that I am not seeing between the two ideas?
Edit:
To be clear, lateral magnification (perpendicular to the optical axis) is consistent and makes sense to me. What I am unsure about is the magnification in the axis of propagation. How come the pulses don't get stretched in space and thus get longer due to axial magnification, but an image of an object would?

can you please elaborate on what is the contradiction? As you said, the magnification happens in the perpendicular directions to the axis of the system, so what seems to be the problem?

A single frequency pulse could only get longer if its frequency were to change, in this case becoming lower, but if nonlinearities are ignored passing through glass does not change the frequency of oscillation.

Laser beam expanders are a commercial item.
